# Specifying a region is mandatory while creating client or resource object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

**Unable to create client or resource object without specifyiing region.These code used to work earlier properly.**

Do I need to change any account settings? Please help

The error occurs at line 2.This happens for all the services such as s3,ec2,sts,iam

```
sess4=boto3.session.Session('root')
resource_ses1=sess4.client('ec2')
ins8=resource_ses1.Instance()
ins8.start()
```

getting the below error

```
NoRegionError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-a13c5dca4ec7> in <module>
      1 sess4=boto3.session.Session('root')
----> 2 resource_ses1=sess4.client('ec2')
      3 ins8=resource_ses1.Instance()
      4 ins.start()

Below is the error:

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\boto3\session.py in client(self, service_name, region_name, api_version, use_ssl, verify, endpoint_url, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, aws_session_token, config)
    261             aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
    262             aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
--> 263             aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
    264 
    265     def resource(self, service_name, region_name=None, api_version=None,

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\botocore\session.py in create_client(self, service_name, region_name, api_version, use_ssl, verify, endpoint_url, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, aws_session_token, config)
    833             is_secure=use_ssl, endpoint_url=endpoint_url, verify=verify,
    834             credentials=credentials, scoped_config=self.get_scoped_config(),
--> 835             client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
    836         monitor = self._get_internal_component('monitor')
    837         if monitor is not None:

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py in create_client(self, service_name, region_name, is_secure, endpoint_url, verify, credentials, scoped_config, api_version, client_config)
     83         client_args = self._get_client_args(
     84             service_model, region_name, is_secure, endpoint_url,
---> 85             verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
     86         service_client = cls(**client_args)
     87         self._register_retries(service_client)

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py in _get_client_args(self, service_model, region_name, is_secure, endpoint_url, verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
    285         return args_creator.get_client_args(
    286             service_model, region_name, is_secure, endpoint_url,
--> 287             verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
    288 
    289     def _create_methods(self, service_model):

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\botocore\args.py in get_client_args(self, service_model, region_name, is_secure, endpoint_url, verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
     71         final_args = self.compute_client_args(
     72             service_model, client_config, endpoint_bridge, region_name,
---> 73             endpoint_url, is_secure, scoped_config)
     74 
     75         service_name = final_args['service_name']

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\botocore\args.py in compute_client_args(self, service_model, client_config, endpoint_bridge, region_name, endpoint_url, is_secure, scoped_config)
    151             is_secure=is_secure,
    152             endpoint_bridge=endpoint_bridge,
--> 153             s3_config=s3_config,
    154         )
    155         # Create a new client config to be passed to the client based

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\botocore\args.py in _compute_endpoint_config(self, service_name, region_name, endpoint_url, is_secure, endpoint_bridge, s3_config)
    216         if service_name == 'sts':
    217             return self._compute_sts_endpoint_config(**resolve_endpoint_kwargs)
--> 218         return self._resolve_endpoint(**resolve_endpoint_kwargs)
    219 
    220     def _compute_s3_endpoint_config(self, s3_config,

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\botocore\args.py in _resolve_endpoint(self, service_name, region_name, endpoint_url, is_secure, endpoint_bridge)
    299                           endpoint_url, is_secure, endpoint_bridge):
    300         return endpoint_bridge.resolve(
--> 301             service_name, region_name, endpoint_url, is_secure)
    302 
    303     def _compute_socket_options(self, scoped_config):

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py in resolve(self, service_name, region_name, endpoint_url, is_secure)
    359         region_name = self._check_default_region(service_name, region_name)
    360         resolved = self.endpoint_resolver.construct_endpoint(
--> 361             service_name, region_name)
    362 
    363         # If we can't resolve the region, we'll attempt to get a global

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\botocore\regions.py in construct_endpoint(self, service_name, region_name, partition_name)
    132         for partition in self._endpoint_data['partitions']:
    133             result = self._endpoint_for_partition(
--> 134                 partition, service_name, region_name)
    135             if result:
    136                 return result

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\botocore\regions.py in _endpoint_for_partition(self, partition, service_name, region_name, force_partition)
    146                 region_name = service_data['partitionEndpoint']
    147             else:
--> 148                 raise NoRegionError()
    149         # Attempt to resolve the exact region for this partition.
    150         if region_name in service_data['endpoints']:

NoRegionError: You must specify a region.
```

Is there any recent change to client and resouce?

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating any resource its better to specify a specific region anyway.

If you have either a `default_region` in a credentials file or `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable then the SDK or CLI will use these to default to a region. This would get around the issue you're seeing.

Alternatively you will need to update your application to use the arguments for regions for each client.

You should try to ensure your code base is always aware of which region its interacting with to avoid headaches when you create resources.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Yeah updating in CLI can be a solution. But actually my question is different. This problem is happening to me only or it's a permanent change in AWS I'm a bit confused. I have default region as us-east-2 and These same line of code used to work before.

Comment: Can't see any changes in https://awsapichanges.info/, although it might be an under the hood change :(

Answer (score 0):

`boto3.session.Session` takes the following [arguments](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html):

```
class boto3.session.Session(
     aws_access_key_id=None, 
     aws_secret_access_key=None, 
     aws_session_token=None, 
     region_name=None, 
     botocore_session=None, 
     profile_name=None)
```

You can use `region_name` or `profile_name` to either given the region explicitly, or use selected profile with the region configured for it.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.Actually my question is, This problem is happening to me only or it's a permanent change in AWS. These same line of code used to work before.

Comment: @SamimRaja Hi. Where do you run it? What version of boto3 you use. Because I'm concerned about this `Session('root')` here? According to docs I posted, Session does not take positional arguments.

Comment: When I start my ec2 instance getting this error now. Please see below:
`resource_ses1=sess4.resource('ec2',region_name='us-ease-2')
ins8=resource_ses1.Instance("instance")
ins8.start()`
`D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\botocore\auth.py in signature(self, string_to_sign, request)
    def signature(self, string_to_sign, request):
         key = self.credentials.secret_key
-->    k_date = self._sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'),
        request.context['timestamp'][0:8])
        k_region = self._sign(k_date, self._region_name)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str`

Comment: boto3 version: 1.14.6

Comment: Seems `self.credentials.secret_key` is not set. Do you have instance role attached to the instance? Where the credentials for your application come from?